Systemd Service not being loaded when migrating from Debian 8 to Yocto
I have an app.service that I have been using on a debian machine that is symlinked to /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants it works well and starts my app.
I have recently been working on switching to using yocto and creating a symlink in the same location but systemctl does not seem to "load" the service. When I try to find my service in systemctl list-unit-files the service does not exist. systemctl status app results in `Unit app.serivce could not be found.
Other services in the multi-user.target.wants are running fine (These are preloaded by yocto)
[Unit]
Description=Main App Runner
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/tyleax/mainapp
ExecStop=/home/tyleax/led-control red
WatchdogSec=60
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Anyone have any idea why the service does not load on yocto, even though it's the same file/permission/symlink?

Is the symlink's target made available at the same time, too? Is /home on the same filesystem as /etc?

Yes they are. Permissions are correct and the symlinks are correct. Interesting observation When I try to create "hard links" I get log messages in systemctl that systemctl cannot load hard links but when I switch back to symlinks I don't see any logs of systemctl attempting to load the service files. If I could find a way to debug I would try that but I have no idea how to debug this, Journal's aren't showing anything either...

What was the full "cannot load hard links" message you mention?

Line1: Jun 15 19:54:49 imx8mn-var-som systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Line2:
Jun 17 05:00:18 imx8mn-var-som systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/app.service is not a symlink, ignoring.
`
This indicates to me that the systemctl does read the files but is not intentionally loading them when they are symlinks?

No, that indicates you linked it into the wrong directory; it won't load the unit from there regardless of type. I think the behavior may differ slightly between systemd versions, though, but that was never meant to be the primary place to put units in. Was that exactly the same location that you used on the previous system?

That error shows up when I do ln -f /home/user/current/services/app.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants
When I run ln -sf /home/user/current/services/app.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants The error doesn't show up but I expect this command to work.
That's how I setup my services on my other system. Am I doing something wrong? I do see the symlinks show up in the right folder afaik.
The ls of the space shows lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   38 Jun 17 05:11 app.service -> /home/user/current/services/app.service

It may be 'the right folder' in the sense that it's where you told ln to put the link, but it's still not the right folder in the sense of where systemd wants it to be. The links in multi-user.target.wants/ are secondary, and are not used for loading the unit; only as an indicator for adding it as a dependency.

Systemd does not load any units from the *.wants directories – unit definitions must be placed in the top-level /etc/systemd/system directory.
The only purpose of *.wants directories is to define additional dependencies between units, and systemd requires a symlink because it doesn't read the files from .wants/ at all – it only reads the symlink target path to determine the name of unit to load, but the actual loading is done through the standard "unit paths" search.
You're supposed to first copy or symlink the unit to the /etc/systemd/system/ toplevel directory for it to become loadable (which is what systemctl link would do for you), and only then it can be symlinked under *.wants/ to be hooked up as a dependency of multi-user.target.
The systemctl link <path> or systemctl enable <path> commands would set up the correct links for you, to be used as an example of what systemd expects:
$ systemctl link ./mkloaderconf.path
Created symlink '/etc/systemd/system/mkloaderconf.path' → '/home/grawity/bin/misc/mkloaderconf.path'.

Trying to 'enable' a unit by its path will automatically call 'link' in current versions:
$ systemctl enable --now ./mkloaderconf.path
Created symlink '/etc/systemd/system/mkloaderconf.path' → '/home/grawity/bin/misc/mkloaderconf.path'.
Created symlink '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mkloaderconf.path' → '/home/grawity/bin/misc/mkloaderconf.path'.


Thank you so much. That helped and fixed my issue. For closure why was it working in my other system where services were only soft linked in multi-user.target.wants?
For context, my other system is "Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) the new yocto system I'm using is 6.1-mickledore (mickledore) Is it because Debian 8 has different expectations for loading services?

I think that's because Debian jessie had an ancient version of systemd, and great many things changed between what's allowed, what's not allowed, and what's "unintended but happens to be allowed". I know loading units from .wants/ was never intended, but I think older versions may have done it anyway – back when the support for linking external units was just first added and the implementation wasn't necessarily as strict as it became later on; the code still had the assumption that everything in .wants/ would be linked from standard paths anyway and that it was "safe" to read it directly.

That makes sense. Thank you again. I was really struggling with this for a while. I was trying a lot of experiments and ending up in dead end. I'll try to start from the basics in the future with recent information/tutorials for systems I'm working with.
